# Estimating sample size required for optimal performance of latent semantic indexing?

Tags: text-mining, svd

Latent semantic indexing seems to work well; e.g. it is independent of language, etc. 
However, it appears to use the similarity of frequencies of terms in the corpus to categorize them.

If this understanding is correct, is there a way to measure the size of the dataset that will give optimal performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background: I've experience in implementing LSA models.

From my experience, there's no real way to predict it. The best way I've found is to generate a number of models based on different parameters and test them with a known task. So if you wanted LSA to categorise documents, you would get a set of docs belonging to different categories (see the Reuters 21578 or the Brown corpus both of which are widely available) and prepare docs from different categories. Then you submit each to each model and see which is the most accurate.

I've also found that the content of documents also affects outcome not just the size of corpus. I won't tell you the specifics but shorter documents tend not to contribute so well to a model's accuracy.

Sorry I can't be of more help in this. I could be wrong about this though - try Google Scholar to see if someone's researched this already and found anything useful.